# Data being sent to new View Controller is nil, unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, error-handling, swift2

When I try to pass details of my `Event` class to another controller I get an error saying `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`.

This is my view controller that sends the info:

```
var eventDetailscontrollers: EventDetailsController!

func showDetailView(event: Events){
    let mainStoryBoarrd: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
    let detailsViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryBoarrd.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("eventDetailsID")
    eventDetailscontrollers?.event = event //this sends all info as nil
    eventDetailscontrollers.event = event //this causes error

    print(event.name)      // this prints event name fine

    self.presentViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the class I send the data to:

```
var event: Events!   {
    didSet  {
        eventPriceLabel.text = event!.date //does nothing
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let string = event?.name
    print(string)// prints null
}
```

My Events class:

```
class Events: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var date: String!
    var address: String!
    var ticketPrice: Int!
```

Comment: It's because `eventDetailscontrollers` is nil in `eventDetailscontrollers?.event = event`

Comment: Are `eventDetailscontrollers` and `detailsViewController` supposed to be the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same view controller

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are declaring the variable `eventDetailscontrollers`, which is as follows:

```
var eventDetailscontrollers: EventDetailsController!
```

But you are never assigning a value to it, so that's why if you call

```
eventDetailscontrollers.event
```

This would crash because `eventDetailscontrollers` is `nil`, so it has no member `event` at that time.

But when you call

```
eventDetailscontrollers?.event
```

This won't crash because you are assigning a value to the `event` member only if `eventDetailscontrollers` is not `nil`, that's what that exclamation mark means. The `eventDetailscontrollers` is actually `nil`, so no assignment is make.

**So you need to initialize the `eventDetailscontrollers` variable first.**

I suggest you read this guide about [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330), and also this one about [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)

Comment: What would the variable be initialized at?

Comment: That depends on what you use that variable for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
func showDetailView(event: Events){
    let mainStoryBoarrd: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
    let detailsViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryBoarrd.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("eventDetailsID")
    eventDetailscontrollers?.event = event //this sends all info as nil
    eventDetailscontrollers.event = event //this causes error

    print(event.name)      // this prints event name fine

    self.presentViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You have two variables that should be the same:

```
func showDetailView(event: Events){
    let mainStoryBoarrd: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
    eventDetailscontrollers = mainStoryBoarrd.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("eventDetailsID")
    eventDetailscontrollers?.event = event //this sends all info as nil
    eventDetailscontrollers.event = event //this causes error

    print(event.name)      // this prints event name fine

    self.presentViewController(eventDetailscontrollers, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```