# Data being sent to new ViewController is being sent as nil

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, error-handling, swift2

When I try to pass details of my Event class to another controller I get an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

This is my view controller that sends the info:

```
var eventDetailsController: EventDetailsController!

func showDetailView(event: Events){
    let mainStoryBoarrd: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",     bundle:nil)
    let detailsViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryBoarrd.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("eventDetailsID")

    print(event)      // this prints the event fine showing that the event variable is not nil
    eventDetailsController?.event = event //this sends all info as nil


    self.presentViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the class I send the data to:

```
var event: Events!   {
    didSet  {
        eventPriceLabel.text = event!.date //does nothing cause nil
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let string = event?.name
    print(string)// prints null
}
```

My Events class:

```
class Events: NSObject {
var name: String!
var date: String!
var address: String!
var ticketPrice: Int!
```

Comment: You're setting the event on `eventDetailsController` then presenting `detailsViewController`.  What's the relationship between those two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data being sent to new View Controller is nil, unwrapping an Optional Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534320/data-being-sent-to-new-view-controller-is-nil-unwrapping-an-optional-value)

Comment: they are the same view controller

Comment: Change `eventDetailsController?.event = event` to `detailsViewController.event = event`

Comment: You already asked this same question, and you have got answers there.

Comment: those answers were incorrect but i found it out! had to add "as! EventDetailsController" to the end of initializing displayViewController and the data sent over